# GDB: programmatically delete a watchpoint

Tags: gdb, watchpoint

Is it possible to delete a watchpoint without knowing the watchpoint number?

I am using commands attached to a breakpoint to set a watchpoint on a memory location. I would like to have the watchpoint cleared at another breakpoint, but I can't figure out how to clear a watchpoint without the watchpoint number. Is there a command that can delete a watchpoint by memory location?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the easiest way is to use the $bpnum convenience variable, you'll probably want to store it in another convenience variable so it doesn't change when you create breakpoints/watchpoints later on.

```
(gdb) watch y
(gdb) set $foo_bp=$bpnum
Hardware watchpoint 2: y
(gdb) p $foo_bp
$1 = 2
(gdb) delete $foo_bp
```

Answer (score 1):

What about saving a watchpoint number and then deleting the watchpoint using this number?

This is an example. I have a C++ program. I set three watchpoints when the breakpoint on the line 5 is hit. For the watchpoint #2 I save a gdb command file in order to delete it later. When the breakpoint on the 9 is hit I just execute this gdb command file:

This is main.cpp:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  int v3=2, v2=1, v1 =0 ;
  printf("Set a watchpoint\n");

  v1 = 1;
  v1 = 2;
  printf("Clear the watchpoint\n");

  v1 = 3;
  v1 = 4;

  return 0;
}
```

This is .gdbinit:

```
file ./a.out
b 5
commands
watch v2
watch v1
set pagination off
shell rm -f all_watchpoints
set logging file all_watchpoints
set logging on
info watchpoints
set logging off
shell rm -f delete_my_watchpoint
shell tail -n 1 all_watchpoints | awk ' {print "delete "$1 }' > delete_my_watchpoint
watch v3
echo Done\n
c
end
b 9
commands
source delete_my_watchpoint
info watchpoints
end
r
```

This is just a sligtly changed version of the .gdbinit that instead of saving a file with the command to delete the watchpoint saves the watchpoint number:

```
file ./a.out
b 5
commands
watch v2
watch v1
set pagination off
shell rm -f all_watchpoints
set logging file all_watchpoints
set logging on
info watchpoints
set logging off
shell rm -f delete_my_watchpoint
shell tail -n 1 all_watchpoints | awk ' {print "set $watchpoint_to_delete_later="$1 }' > save_my_watchpoint_number
source save_my_watchpoint_number
shell rm -f save_my_watchpoint_number
shell rm -f all_watchpoints
watch v3
echo Done\n
c
end
b 9
commands
delete $watchpoint_to_delete_later
info watchpoints
end
r
```

If you set a watchpoint using an address in this way:

```
(gdb) watch *((int*)0x22ff44)
Hardware watchpoint 3: *((int*)0x22ff44)
(gdb) info watchpoints
Num     Type           Disp Enb Address    What
3       hw watchpoint  keep y              *((int*)0x22ff44)
```

You can also later find this address since it is dislayed in `info watchpoints`

```
(gdb) set logging file all_watchpoints
(gdb) set logging on
Copying output to all_watchpoints.
(gdb) info watchpoints
Num     Type           Disp Enb Address    What
3       hw watchpoint  keep y              *((int*)0x22ff44)
4       hw watchpoint  keep y              *((int*)0x22ff48)
5       hw watchpoint  keep y              *((int*)0x22ff4B)
(gdb) set logging of
Done logging to all_watchpoints.
(gdb) shell grep 0x22ff48 all_watchpoints
4       hw watchpoint  keep y              *((int*)0x22ff48)
(gdb) shell grep 0x22ff48 all_watchpoints | awk ' {print $1}'
4
(gdb) shell grep 0x22ff48 all_watchpoints | awk ' {print "delete "$1}' > delete_watchpoint
(gdb) source delete_watchpoint
(gdb) info watchpoints
Num     Type           Disp Enb Address    What
3       hw watchpoint  keep y              *((int*)0x22ff44)
5       hw watchpoint  keep y              *((int*)0x22ff4B)
```